# Tkinter text widget deforms column size

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I can't pack widgets in rows or columns as in image, can you help me?

[image]

The problem is text widget deforms column size, text should not be in row=3,column=0 ?

[image]

```
   def _formato(self):
    t1=tkinter.Toplevel(self._finestra)
    labelTop = tkinter.Label(t1,text = "Tipo di carattere")
    labelTop.grid(row=0, column=0)
    labelTop2 = tkinter.Label(t1,text = "Dimensione")
    labelTop2.grid(row=0, column=1)
    labelTop3 = tkinter.Label(t1)
    labelTop3.grid(row=2, column=0)
    listaFont=tkinter.ttk.Combobox(t1)
    allfonts = sorted(tkinter.font.families())
    listaFont["values"] =  allfonts
    listaFont.grid(row=1, column=0)
    listaFont.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", None)
    listaDimensione = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(t1)
    allfontsizes = list(range(8,70))
    listaDimensione['values'] =  allfontsizes
    listaDimensione.grid(row=1, column=1)
    testo= tkinter.Text(t1)
    testo.insert(tkinter.INSERT,'AaBbYyZz')
    testo.grid(row=3,column=0)
```

Comment: Read [gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid/34277295#34277295)

Comment: Can you please add some more details what you are trying to achieve, what is working and what isn't?

Comment: @Jere: The OP want to layout widgets in a `grid` manner, but uses `pack` without options.

Comment: @stovfl I was not clear yesterday. the problem is text widget deforms column size.  I could change the width of it but it is not accurate...

Comment: @stovfl No sorry, only in row=3 ,column=0  and row=4, column=0.But it goes well beyond the column 0

Comment: @antonio You want the `Text` to be equal `width` as the above `Label(t1, text="Tipo di carattere")`?

Comment: @stovfl  Yes. At the moment I solved by modifying the width of the Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: All widgets in the same `column` should have equal `width`.

The core is, use a `Frame` for every column and layout the widgets into the `Frame`.
This allows all widgets to resize to the `Frame width`.
[image]

---

1. Define `class App` for demonstration purpose

   ```
   class App(tk.Tk):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
   ```
2. To get equal `width` use a `tk.Frame` for every column.
   Allow the `Frame` to grow his `width`.
   Allow the widgets inside the `Frame` to grow his `width`.
   Define the `Frame` to grow up to the `App width`.

   ```
           # column 0
           self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
           frame_0 = tk.Frame(self)
           frame_0.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
           frame_0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
   ```
3. Add the widgets ...
   Define every widget to grow his `width` up to the `Frame width`.

   ```
           labelTop = tkinter.Label(frame_0, text="Tipo di carattere")
           labelTop.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')

           listaFont = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(frame_0)
           listaFont.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
           allfonts = sorted(tkinter.font.families())
           listaFont["values"] = allfonts
           listaFont.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", None)
   ```
4. **Note**: Reset the default using `width=1`

   ```
           testo = tkinter.Text(frame_0, width=1)
           testo.insert(tkinter.INSERT, 'AaBbYyZz')
           testo.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='ew')
   ```
5. The same for columen 1 ...

   ```
           # column 1
           self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
           frame_1 = tk.Frame(self)
           frame_1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
           frame_1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

           labelTop2 = tkinter.Label(frame_1, text="Dimensione")
           labelTop2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')

           listaDimensione = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(frame_1)
           allfontsizes = list(range(8, 70))
           listaDimensione['values'] = allfontsizes
           listaDimensione.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
   ```

> **Usage**:

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: only question, why using width=1 on Text? 
testo = tkinter.Text(frame_0, width=1)

Comment: @antonio: `Text` widget is greedy about `width/height`, it instantiats with a hugh `width`. It's a workaround to force the `width` to obey the `Frame width`.

Comment: @antonio *" place frame inside a toplevel?"*: It's the same, change to `class App(tk.Toplevel):` and in `__main__` do at first `root = tk.Tk()`. The `root` is used by default.

Comment: Only a problem,I set the height of Text widget to 3, when I increase the font size  it grows in height...

Comment: @antonio: Read about [how-to-stop-tkinter-text-widget-resize-on-font-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833698/how-to-stop-tkinter-text-widget-resize-on-font-change/9839014#9839014)