# How to stop Tkinter ScrolledText widget resize on font change?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scrolledtext

When I try to increase the `font` size the `scrolledtext` widget also increases and I want to keep the size of the `scrolledtext` widget unchanged no matter how I increase the size of the `font`.

[When font size is 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAt6r.png)
[When font size is 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQKl1.png)

as you look at the photo the `scrolledtext` widget change it's size when the `font` size changes and I want to stop my `scrolledtext` size from changing

```py
# import GUI
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import Spinbox

# create instance
win = tk.Tk()

# title name
win.title("Notepad ver.1.0")

# resizable option
win.resizable(True, True)

# geometry
win.geometry("1900x1000")


def click(e):
    GetFont = 'Arial, ' + str(FontSize.get())
    scr.configure(font=GetFont)

# frame 1
frame1 = ttk.LabelFrame(win, text='')
frame1.grid(column=0, row=0)

# font size
ttk.Label(frame1, text='Font Size:').grid(column=1, row=2)

# font spin box
FontSize = Spinbox(frame1, from_=10, to=60, width=4)
FontSize.grid(column=2, row=2)


# frame2
frame2 = ttk.LabelFrame(win, text='')
# set the width and height of your frame as desired using ipadx and ipady
frame2.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=tk.S, ipadx=100, ipady=100)
# disable grid propagation to prevent resizing on font size changes
frame2.grid_propagate(False)

# scrolled text
ScrWidth = 150
ScrHight = 30
scr = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame2, width=ScrWidth, height=ScrHight)
scr.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
scr.config(font='Arial, 10')
scr.grid_propagate(False)

scr.insert(tk.INSERT, 'Sample Text')

win.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", click)

# start GUI
win.mainloop()
```

I tried to google it and found some stackoverflow questions and I did what they suggested but it didn't work for my code.

Here is the link of the stackoverflow question:
[How to stop Tkinter Text widget resize on font change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833698/how-to-stop-tkinter-text-widget-resize-on-font-change)

Comment: It would be good to just give us the minimum working code necessary to illustrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Lee-xp thank you for your comment I will keep in mind when I ask at stackoverflow later

Comment: If you're going to update the code posted with your question, there's really no need to keep the old code in the body of the question.

Comment: @JRiggles Got it! I will delete the old code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `ScrolledText` widget is contained in a `Frame`, you'll want to disable `grid_propagate` for that `Frame`. Then you'll need to set the internal padding for the parent frame with `ipadx` and `ipady`, otherwise it will have 0 width and height

```
# set the width and height of your frame as desired using ipadx and ipady
frame2.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=tk.S, ipadx=500, ipady=300)
# disable grid propagation to prevent resizing on font size changes
frame2.grid_propagate(False)
```